# JAWS not reading <legend> within <fieldset> within dynamic framework

Tags: knockout.js, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I'm doing accessibility work on a dynamically built quiz within a larger site (we're using Knockout bindings to populate the questions.) I'm currently working on our radio buttons questions. We originally had some Knockout that stuck "aria-labeledby" in appropriate places, but we decided it would have faster load times to do it properly with fieldsets and legends.

Only in our framework, using JAWS 12 in IE8, focusing on a radio element only reads its label and not the legend as I'd expect.

I even took this simple example code, which works find off our site. When I stuck it inside our framework and it stops reading the legend.

```
<fieldset id="eyeColor">
<legend>Eye Color</legend>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio" name="eye_color" id="blueEyes"/> <label for="blueEyes">Blue</label> </li>
<li><input type="radio" name="eye_color" id="brownEyes"/> <label for="brownEyes">Brown</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="eye_color" id="greenEyes"/> <label for="greenEyes">Green</label></li>
<li><input type="radio" name="eye_color" id="otherEyes"/> <label for="otherEyes">Other</label></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

I know I should post the entire HTML from our site (it's built from a number of templates,) but it's gigantic.

Here's the some earlier bits I'm concerned about:

```
<div class="loading" data-bind="'visible': !Items.loaded(), 'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <span data-bind="'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" aria-hidden="true">Just one moment while we access this information...</span>
</div>
<div class="loading" data-bind="'visible': !Items.loaded(), 'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <span data-bind="'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" aria-hidden="true">Just one moment while we access this information...</span>
</div>

    <div data-bind="'css': ItemStateIdentifiers" class="Container Slide TuftsUniversityWLQ-TroubleStarting" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Well-being Module, Work Performance Subject" style="outline: none;">
<div class="loading" data-bind="'visible': !Items.loaded(), 'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
    <span data-bind="'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" aria-hidden="true">Just one moment while we access this information...</span>
</div>
```

```
<div class="loading" data-bind="'visible': !Items.loaded(), 'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
        <span data-bind="'attr': { 'aria-hidden': Items.loaded() }" aria-hidden="true">Just one moment while we access this information...</span>
</div>
```

And here's the actual radio question:

```
    <h3 class="title" data-bind="'html': Title, 'visible': Title">In the past 2 weeks, how much of the time did your physical health or emotional problems make it     <span>difficult</span> for you to...</h3>
    <p class="userTip" data-bind="'foreach': Text, 'visible': Text.length &gt; 0" style="display: none;"></p>
    <div class="QuestionGroupItemsPlaceholder" data-bind="'template': {'name':TemplateNameLookup,'foreach': NonSkippedItems}">
    <div data-bind="'css': ItemStateIdentifiers" class="Question LineConnectedRadio WLQ-SlowStartToDay valid">
<label class="questionText" data-bind="'attr': {'for': ClientName}, 'foreach': Text" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay">
        <span data-bind="'text': text, 'css': css" class="text">Get going easily at the beginning of the workday</span>
</label>
<div class="line opts6" data-bind="'css': 'opts' + choices.length"></div>
    <fieldset role="radiogroup">
        <legend class="accessibility" data-bind="'text':Text[0].text, 'attr':{ 'id': 'lbl-' + ClientName() }" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay">Get going easily at the beginning of the workday</legend>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: choices, css: 'opts' + choices.length" class="opts6">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="4" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx0">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx0" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx0" class="">Difficult None of the time</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="3" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx1">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx1" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx1" class="checked">Difficult a Slight Bit of the time</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="2" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx2">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx2" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx2" class="">Difficult Some of the time</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="1" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx3">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx3" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx3" class="">Difficult Most of the time</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="0" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx4">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx4" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx4" class="">Difficult All of the time</label>
            </li>

            <li>
                <input type="radio" data-bind="'value': Value, 'checked': $parent.Answer, 'attr': { 'name': $parent.ClientName, 'id': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index()}, 'trackFocus': true" name="WLQ-SlowStartToDay" value="5" id="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx5">
                <label data-bind="'text': Text, 'attr': { 'for': $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index(), 'id': 'lbl-' + $parent.ClientName() + '-idx' + $index() }, 'css': { 'checked': Value === $parent.Answer() }" for="WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx5" id="lbl-WLQ-SlowStartToDay-idx5" class="">Does not apply to my job</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
```

Do folks have any ideas what I might be inheriting that's causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope you find this resource useful: http://www.deque.com/aria-group-viable-alternative-fieldset-legend (extensive testing of various solutions you describe)

Comment: Is the `legend` visible or hidden (`display:none;`)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, FelipeAls. Will look at now.

Comment: unor, the legend is currently hidden (not display: none;, just moved off screen), but I also tested it with legend visible, to see if that was the issue.

Comment: Legend elements are not reliably announced by screenreader software; as you've found, JAWS wants to skip it. Fieldset elements are also a bit dodgy. The name on the radio elements will be reliably announced though, and with a paragraph or span for your sighted users should be enough to convey that this is a group of related inputs.

Comment: try setting the require aria attributes - http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties

Comment: pressing `INSERT+ESC` refreshes JAWS' virtual buffer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> just after your character set meta tag in the head and let me know if that clears it up.